# How to enable install only on exect device

Tags: android, installation, apk, device

Good day.

I got android application and i need to disable installing on all devices exept those which listed in application config. So how do i disable installing on all other devices (in application`s code)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible yet.

Android apps can be disabled from installing based on `minSdkVersion` and `screen sizes`. There is no parameter suggesting not install based on vendors.

The best option you have is to find out on application launch, which device you are currently on and then show a message stating you cannot run on this phone/tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can control the selective installation behavior, however you may disable the execution of your application components (activity/service/broadcast-receiver) in case your device criteria doesn't meet.